# Add an Array to a LineChart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add an Array to my line Chart, but the SeriesCollection does not support this property or method. Most example online creates an array and bind it to SeriesCollection.Values.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'Declare
Dim WS As Worksheet, posX As Integer
Dim posY As Integer, sizeX As Integer, SizeY As Integer
Dim arr1 As Variant

' Init
posX = 100: posY = 0
sizeX = 500: SizeY = 300

' Set Sheet
Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
WS.Activate

' Plot Data
WS.Range("A3:B12").Select
arr1 = Array(10, 15, 12, 25, 35, 20)


' Configure Chart
Dim ch As Chart
Set ch = WS.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine, posX, posY, sizeX, SizeY).Chart
With ch
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "My Chart Title"
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection.Values = arr1
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part processing the newly created chart should look like:

```
     With ch
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = "My Chart Title"     
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = arr1 'you need to specify WHICH seresCollection
    End With
```

or doing it on a single code line, not needing to know how many series have previously been added:

```
       .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr1
```